# How to align items on the far left and items on the far right of a HTML/Javascript list?

Tags: javascript, html, list, listview, alignment

I'm struggling to be able to format a list of items how i'd like.

Id like items placed on the far left and items placed of the far right.

Here's a link to illustrate what i mean.

[list arrangement](http://oi64.tinypic.com/mcvia8.jpg)

How would i go about doing this? I've heard that a table would probably be the easiest but I've also been told to try to stay away from tables.

Comment: Hi, have you tried float:left; and float:right;? Can you please upload your code so that we can solve your problem

Comment: You can add a jsfiddle link or a code snippet of what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating two `<div>`s, one for the data you would like on the left, and one for the data on the right. Then use `text-align:left` and `text-align:right`, respectively as CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually recommend tables, this seems like *tabular* data.. wink on the word tabular as in tables are meant for tabular data.
If you still want to use lists tho, I would recommend to do 2 lists and have tableA float: left, and have tableB float: right;

check this fiddle out:

https://jsfiddle.net/selda_uxunicorn/assektkm/

CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.tableA {
  float: left;
}

.tableB{
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="tableA">
<li>this item</li>
<li>this other item</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tableB">
<li>item</li>
<li>another item</li>
</ul>
```